Is this an ordinary workplace experience for an intern?
I'm nearing the completion of my internship in a tech company in a small town. The hours are good and the pay is decent, so in that sense, I'm immensely grateful.
But I have terrible imposter syndrome. I feel that I'm competent for my job, but culturally / socially I don't fit in at all. Since the office is half remote, the day I joined, the entire office was silent, and I was extremely isolated. My boss, who was there that day, was too busy to talk to me beyond a few words.
Since then, my work has been fairly isolated like that as well. I spend upwards of nearly the entire day working solo without seemingly talking with anybody. I join the team for lunch, with lasts less than 9 minutes as everybody rushes to eat and then immediately go back to work. Nobody talks in the office unless they want to report on their work-progress, but they don't seem particularly stressed either. It's as if they just don't want to be friends with each other. I've tried talking with them and it's like talking to a brick wall. It goes nowhere.
I have a distinct feeling something happened to these people, but I can't tell, because they just don't talk. Over the course of my internship I've undergone tremendous imposter syndrome because sometimes I felt like it was me (there is a cultural difference in terms of ethnicity, race / my team is not very diverse).
It doesn't help that everytime a full-time joins, my boss sends a memo to the entire team, but when I joined there was zero fanfare. I end today and the week has been uneventful as expected.
I've done some good work, so I'm happy about that, but I'm really mixed about my experiences.
Is this representative of tech companies? I'm graduating soon and I get really scared thinking that this depressing, isolated life could be my future.
tl;dr : nobody at work socializes and I have imposter syndrome because of it; I've heard tech is stereotypically antisocial, is this representative of tech?
Edit: Thank you everyone for your advice, warm comments, and reassurance. I'm glad to hear that this isn't the norm in the industry. I'm thinking when I look for full time I'll try digging a little deeper into company culture next time. Hoping for the best! :)

What country are you in?

Unrelated, but I suspect you meant that tech is stereotypically asocial – not antisocial.
With that said, pretty much all the teams I have worked with over a decade in the industry had socializing events (Canada).

Was this an internship through a program of your university or school? If so you may want to provide feedback to the program manager at your uni/school about this.

@Jean-FrançoisSavard Yes, you're correct. I meant asocial, not antisocial.

Every company is different. Sorry that this company failed in the purpose of having an internship program.
You should have been able to expect to learn from them some basics of the industry and their style of working environment. You also should have expected to gain comfort and confidence in working in your field.
It sounds like you didn't get those things from them.
As you go forward and interview with other companies attempt to learn more about their culture. Glassdoor, etc. can help.
Bottomline is no, this isn't what to expect. Yes, it happens sometimes.

Thanks for your advice. I had checked glassdoor before joining and it seemed fine. I think it might be my team in particular; do you have any advice for learning about team culture before joining?

@Yartholomev while your first job and/or internship can feel daunting, try to remember that the interview process is a two-way process. Yes-that is much eaiser said than done. These are just people that you will be talking to. The key thing is that they want sucess also. Have a reasonable idea of what you are looking for from a company. You are there to provide service to them, and they are providing career growth to you. Don't expect the company's full time job to be your career growth and you'll be good. Ask about the team that you will be assigned. Look for a good fit.


Is this representative of tech companies?

No.
Most companies have a very open and friendly work environment. IT workers usually chat, talk, and socialize with one another during a few quick breaks throughout the whole work days (as long as the chats are not too loud and do not bother someone, and they do not take too much time away from doing the real work).
Socializing between coworkers builds better work relationship, and improves the collaboration between team members and teams. Therefore, it also increases the productivity, and enhances quality of the products.
In addition, those little fun and friendly chats during the quick breaks will also reduce your stress due to hard work on tough projects, and give you a refreshing mindset to tackle difficult problems when you get back to your desk. It will definitely help you come up with better solutions for your projects.
Socializing with coworkers is better for your mental health in the long run.
The legendary Greek philosopher Aristotle once said: “Man is by nature a social animal."

The work culture at your current company is not the common culture in the IT industry (at least not in the US in my experience).

"The work culture at your current company is not the common culture in the IT industry" Agreed, that is my experience in The Netherlands as well.

@MarkRotteveel, Yes. The great majority of countries in the world would have the same work culture that is very open and friendly, which allows coworkers to socialize at work. :-)
